# Python parallelization (multiprocessing) BrokenPipe with telnet

Tags: python, multiprocessing, telnet, broken-pipe

I am writing a script with GUI to control a device (DDS). The DDS is controlled with telnet and because of timing issues I run it in a separate process. The script connects to the device, but when trying to set the frequency output I get the Errno 32 Broken pipe BrokenPipeError.

I double-checked the connection using Telnet via the terminal and by running only the part of the code responsible for the connection (which is then in the main process). In both cases everything runs smoothly and I get no errors. Problem happens when I run the full script with GUI and the telnet connection happens in a separate process. Here is the output:

```
DDS connected!
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jakubdobosz/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-j.dobosz2@student.uw.edu.pl/Mój dysk/github/FrequencyDriftStabilizer/gui.py", line 46, in _handleStab
    handler.filterUpdate()
  File "/Users/jakubdobosz/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-j.dobosz2@student.uw.edu.pl/Mój dysk/github/FrequencyDriftStabilizer/src/handlerStabilization.py", line 155, in filterUpdate
    self._DDS.setFreq(self._DDSfreq)
  File "/Users/jakubdobosz/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-j.dobosz2@student.uw.edu.pl/Mój dysk/github/FrequencyDriftStabilizer/src/DDS_AD9912.py", line 91, in setFreq
    self._DDS.write(cmd.encode('UTF-8'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/telnetlib.py", line 292, in write
    self.sock.sendall(buffer)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Is there a way to communicate with the device through telnet in a subprocess? Or maybe there is another problem, not the one I assumed.

Comment: 'and the telnet connection happens in a separate process' -> are you perhaps, creating a connection-object on one process and then try to use it on another? Try to write some sample code with multiprocessing that reflects your usage pattern.

Comment: No, the entire communication is held in this secondary process. I tried with simplified code and it works. Now I guess that it is small sampling period, I increased it by order of magnitude and it works.

Comment: If the entire communication is happening on one multiprocessing-process than I don't think multiprocessing is the problem.

Comment: If you solved it (sampling?) you can post your answer here.